# Why does vscode error every time I try to install kivy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I am trying to install kivy using the vscode terminal in windows 10, and I am getting this error:
[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4oZO.png)

This happens every time I use commands like:
`python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --no-binary kivy`
`python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples`
`python -m pip install kivy`

All help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to python 3.9.9. As of writing this, Kivy is not updated for python 3.10.+

Had the exact same issue earlier this week when I first started using kivy. If you use python 3.10.0 for anything else, you'll want to look into virtual environments (VS Code actually makes it really easy to change virtual envs).